# Hibernate + Ireports

Tags: java, html5, hibernate, spring-mvc, netbeans

Estou tentando fazer a conexão de um projeto Spring MVC com Hibernate utilizando JSP.
Mas um problema aparece quando tento criar uma conexão para importar dados a um report usando a tecnologia JasperReports + Ireport. Quando seleciono a Opção Spring loaded Hibernate connection, e quando carrego o `spring-servlet.xml` um erro aparece:

```
Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [spring-servlet.xml];nest exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'component-scan' and its parser class[org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanbenaDefinitionParser]are only available on JDk 1.5 and higher.
```

[image: Foto de quando acontece o erro em seu ambiente.]

O que foi utilizado:

- Spring framework 4.0.6
- Hibernate 4
- Netbeans 8.0 patch 2
- JDK 1.8
- JRE 8
- Plugin para Netbeans

  - Ireport 5.6
  - Jasperreports 5.6

Já verifiquei se todas as configurações do JDK estão corretas e o caminho do JDK está no `PATH` e `classpath` e no CMD quando dou o comando `java -version` é exibido a versão `java_version "1.8.0_05"`.

Alguém saberia resolver este erro?